# Connecting with Database in Java in different Frames

Tags: java, sql, database, jframe

I have some doubt when accessing to my SQL DB. The thing is I have a connect Button with this code:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

    Object opc = arg0.getSource();

    if (opc.equals(v.conectar))
    {
        Connection conexion = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            conexion = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/colegio", "root", "12345");
            Statement stm = conexion.createStatement();

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "CONEXION ESTABLECIDA CON EXITO");

            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

In that button, as you see, I connect perfectly with my DB. The problem appears when I need to acced to that Statement object from other JInternalFrame:

```
public class boton_alta_cliente implements ActionListener {

ventanaAlta v;

boton_alta_cliente(ventanaAlta v) {
    this.v=v;
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0, Statement STM) {

    Object opc = arg0.getSource();

    if (opc.equals(v.alta))
    {
        ResultSet RS = STM.executeQuery("query");
    }

}
}
```

How can I use that connection I made in my first button, in the JInternalFrame that I use for sign up my clients?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a separate class in your project that handles JDBC connections. So for example, you could have a class called "JDBC" which creates a connection in a "connect()" method. You could then call that connection from your other classes like so:

```
Connection connect = JDBC.connect();
```

Answer (score 0):

Like any reference to an object that you want to share between objects, it has to be defined not as a local variable but as a (preferably private) field. You create a getter method for it, and the other frame can use the getter method to access the connection. The same goes for the prepared statement.